# Generate probability function with mean M?

Tags: distributions, random-generation

I'd like to generate random probabilities with a specified mean and deviation.

A "Flat" random number [0-1] will result in a mean of 0.5 and an SD ~ .29.

I'd like to generate random probabilities with a specified mean (maybe 0.9 or 0.2) and also test the effect of "narrowing" the variance.  I'll then put these in a set of calculations to see how they effect the overall result.

Comment: If you need the numbers restricted to [0,1], consider a beta distribution where you can set the mean and standard deviation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution

Comment: Yes, Thanks!  The inverse Beta function works over a random input from [0,1].  Mean is easy to specify from alpha and beta.  Variance for a specific mean is challenging, but doable!

Comment: $a=\frac{\mu  \left(\mu  (1-\mu )-\sigma ^2\right)}{\sigma ^2}$ and $b=\frac{(1-\mu ) \left(\mu  (1-\mu )-\sigma ^2\right)}{\sigma ^2}$.  And, of course, $0<\mu<1$ and there are restrictions on the values that $\sigma^2$ can take depending on $\mu$.

Comment: Yes.  If I assert that the average probability should be X it's easy to set with a/(a+b).  Then "scaling" a and b smaller increases variance for a fixed mean, and scaling them larger reduces variance for that mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the numbers restricted to [0,1], consider a [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) where you can set the mean and standard deviation.

If you set the mean ($\mu$) and variance ($\sigma^2$), then the values of $a$ and $b$ can be determined

$$a=\frac{\mu  \left(\mu  (1-\mu )-\sigma ^2\right)}{\sigma ^2}$$
$$b=\frac{(1-\mu ) \left(\mu  (1-\mu )-\sigma ^2\right)}{\sigma ^2}$$

with the restrictions $0<\mu<1$ and $0<\sigma^2 \le \mu (1-\mu)$.